# HibernateTemplate save() is not inserting data into database with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I tried but could not find the right answer could you pleasehelp me out?
Table is creating but data is not getting inserted.I fixed the above error but data is not inserting in db for Hibernatetemplate save().

Comment: call saveOrUpdate() method instead of save() and also check your class implements Serializable

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PankajMandale Using saveOrUpdate is not a good practice tho. You should know if you are creating or updating a row. Leaving it to Hibernate is slower and can lead to architecture issues.

Comment: I am sharing my DAoImpemaentation class coyld you find out error why the data is not inserting into database

Comment: Pankaj Mandale can you see my code which is below

Comment: @PankajMandale Hi i have posted my DAOIMplementation class I was struct for 2 days looking into this but I could not get m question solved. I have even tried save() return type as serializable. could you please help me with this boss

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false)
public class StudentDaoImplHT implements StudentDao {

    private HibernateTemplate ht;
    public void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht) {
        this.ht = ht;
    }
     @Transactional
    @Override
    public int save(Student st) {
    int i=(Integer) ht.save(st);;


    System.out.println(st.getId());
        System.out.println(st.getAddress());
        System.out.println(st.getEmail());
        System.out.println(st.getName());



            return i;   }
    @Override
    public boolean update(Student st) {
        ht.saveOrUpdate(st);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean delete(Student st) {
        //ht.delete(st);
        return true;    
}
@Override
    public Student findByPK(int id ) {
    Student std=(Student) ht.get(Student.class, id);
    return std;
    }
@Override
    public List<Student> findByAllUsingHQL() {
        List<Student> list=(List<Student>) ht.find("from Student");
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Student> findByAllUsingCriteria() {
        DetachedCriteria dc=DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class);
        //dc.setProjection(projection);
        //ht.findByCriteria(criteria)
        List<Student> list= (List<Student>) ht.findByCriteria(dc);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following property in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
"hibernate.connection.autocommit" true"

property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" true property
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just used @EnableTransactionManagement on my DAO class & this actually worked for me.